# qTip positioning within a tooltip

Tags: jquery, qtip2

So I have qTip2 working succesffuly, displaying the tooltip as a modal for some ajax content.  Everything is working great, except the content within the modal tooltip has links that also call another tooltip.  When I click any of those, the positioning goes way off screen (like -234.5px and -300px).

I know it has something to do with the position parameters, but I can't get it to work.  Could I make it use the target of the previously clicked tooltip as its position?  Or is there a way to load the new ajax content in the same tooltip?

link on main page:

```
<a class="qtipajaxmodal" id="[id here]" href="[link here]" 
    rel="[ajax link here]">Main Link</a>
```

link within ajax pulled content:

```
<a class="qtipajaxmodal" id="[id here]" href="[link here]" 
    rel="[ajax link to somewhere else here]">Another Link</a>
```

qTip code:

```
// Make sure to only match links to wikipedia with a rel tag
       $('a.qtipajaxmodal').live('mouseover', function() {
           // Make sure to only apply one tooltip per element!
            if( $(this).data('qtip') === 'object' ){ return; } 

          $(this).qtip({
            id: 'modal2', 
            content: {

            text: '<div class="ajaxqtipmodal-load" alt="Loading..."></div>',
                ajax: {
                   url: $(this).attr('rel') 
                },
                title: {
                   text: 'Title: - ' + $(this).text(), 
                   button: true
                }
             },
              events: {
                 show: function(event, api) {
                     // Grab the tooltip element from the API
                     var tooltip = api.elements.tooltip
                     // ...and here's the extra event binds
                     tooltip.find('.ui-tooltip-titlebar').show();
                  },
                  hide: function(event, api) { 
                    //api.destroy(); 
                  }
               },
             position: {
                 target: $('#main'),
                 container: $('#main'),
                 my: 'center', // ...at the center of the viewport
                 at: 'center',
                 //viewport: $('#container'),
                 effect: false
             },
             show: {
                event: 'click',
                solo: true, // Only show one tooltip at a time
                modal: true,
                effect: function(offset) {
                    $(this).show(400); // "this" refers to the tooltip
                } // ...and make it modal

             },
             hide: false,
             style: {
                classes: 'ui-tooltip-fd-movie'
             }
         }).click(function(event) { event.preventDefault(); });
       });[/code]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a similar problem. I believe it is because the links are visible at load so qTip puts the position off the screen. I would apply qTip to the new links after the ajax content loads.

Edit:

Try adding qTip on the show event of the first qTip:

```
show: function(event, api) {
    $(".qtipajaxmodal").qTip(...);
}
```

Comment: Do you mean the links are not visible at load?  The new link is generated from the ajax call of the first qtip.  How do I apply it after it new content loads?  Give it a different class?  Thanks for your help!

Comment: It has to do with the solo property in show.  When set to true, the qtip links with the current qTip aren't able to calculate the position properly.  When solo is off it seems to work.  Wouldn'nt the above edit require me to nest a show function for each time I needed to pull a qtip from within a qtip?  Is there a way to just put the content in the current qTip?